# Pandas groupby, perform operations, add results to column inside said groupby dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Assume the following dataframe foo (constructed here with sub-dataframes for showcasing purposes):

```
foo1 = pd.DataFrame({"TIME":(np.arange(1,10,1))})
foo1['Letter'] = 'A'
foo1['Number'] = 50
foo1['Variable1'] = np.random.uniform(10,100, size=len(foo1))
foo1['Variable2'] = np.random.uniform(10,100, size=len(foo1))
foo1['Variable3'] = np.random.uniform(10,100, size=len(foo1))

foo2 = pd.DataFrame({"TIME":(np.arange(1,20,0.5))})
foo2['Letter'] = 'A'
foo2['Number'] = 100
foo2['Variable1'] = np.random.uniform(10,100, size=len(foo2))
foo2['Variable2'] = np.random.uniform(10,100, size=len(foo2))
foo2['Variable3'] = np.random.uniform(10,100, size=len(foo2))

foo3 = pd.DataFrame({"TIME":(np.arange(1,40,2.5))})
foo3['Letter'] = 'B'
foo3['Number'] = 40
foo3['Variable1'] = np.random.uniform(10,100, size=len(foo3))
foo3['Variable2'] = np.random.uniform(10,100, size=len(foo3))
foo3['Variable3'] = np.random.uniform(10,100, size=len(foo3))

foo = pd.concat([foo1,foo2,foo3])
```

The dataframe is in reality much larger (millions of rows). I would like to perform some calculations on the underlying subdataframes and assign the result to a new column. I use groupby to split them. Then I would like for instance to find the cummulative percentage change with respect to the first value for variable 1 and also for the mean of all three variables and assign that to a new column.

Currently, I am making a list of dataframes with groupby, and then iterating over dataframes as such:

```
df_split = [g for _, g in foo.groupby(['Letter','Number'])]

for i,df in enumerate(df_split):
    df['Perc1'] = df['Variable1'].pct_change().cumsum()*100
    df['MeanPerc'] = df[['Variable1','Variable2','Variable3']].mean(axis=1).pct_change().cumsum()*100
    df['Var1Ratio'] = df['TIME'].iloc[0]/df['Variable1']

foo_end = pd.concat(df_split)
```

I am pretty sure there is a more efficient way to do this, avoiding the list of dataframes part; it gets too slow when the df size increases. But i can't really figure out how to perform these computations on the groupby object and assign them back to the groupby object. Calculations need to be done per sub-dataframe as the first entry is important.

If not possible directly with groupby, is there a faster/better way to do this?

I would be grateful for any suggestions :-)

Comment: This should be something wrong with `pct_change`, so the safe way is to do what you have done  right now ..

Comment: what do you mean something wrong?

Comment: Check https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21200 so that , `df.groupby([]).pct_change()` not return the correct result

Comment: ok, but the question goes beyond the `.pct_change()` . Any calculation, i would like to be able to do on the subdataframes, so the result of the  `.groupby()`